# Add Additional File Info (jpeg compression & file size) settings to Edit Images Screen

Tags: plugin-development, media-library, compression

On the WordPress Edit Image Screen, I'd like to add a label to show the current compression level and byte file size of the image.

Any ideas how to tap into this screen and echo this data?

The current settings show:

- Date
- URL
- File name
- File type
- Dimensions

I'd like to ad

- File Size
- File Compression (echo the current jpeg_quality setting)

Comment: Is it possible to inspect a jpg file compression? [Looks like not...](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1546923/1287812)

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but the current wordpress setting for jpeg_quality should be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use the  `attachment_submitbox_misc_actions` filter to add more info to the box. Here is an example for the filesize part:

[image]

```
add_action( 'attachment_submitbox_misc_actions', 'custom_fileinfo_wpse_98608' );
function custom_fileinfo_wpse_98608(){
    global $post;
    $meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $post->ID );
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $filepath = $upload_dir['basedir']."/".$meta['file'];
    $filesize = filesize($filepath);
    ?>
    <div class="misc-pub-section">
        <?php _e( 'File Size:' ); ?> <strong><?php echo $filesize; ?> </strong> <?php _e( 'bytes' ); ?>             
    </div>
<?php
}
```

The default file info is displayed with the `attachment_submitbox_metadata()` function through this action:

```
add_action( 'attachment_submitbox_misc_actions', 'attachment_submitbox_metadata' );
```

in the file `/wp-admin/includes/media.php`

Comment: +1 Works perfectly. Now I just need to figure out how to echo the site's jpeg_quality setting

Comment: ok great, thanks for sharing your jpeg_quality solution.

Answer (score 2):

This 2 functions will work with custom mime uploaded files (like PSD, EPS)  when meta not avaible. It also returns more then just a lot of bytes, means, 2 decimal logic unit. The 99 places the info last in the meta box.

```
// Helper
function ua_formatBytes($bytes, $precision = 2) { 
        $units = array('B', 'kB', 'mB', 'GB', 'TB'); 
        $bytes = max($bytes, 0); 
        $pow = floor(($bytes ? log($bytes) : 0) / log(1024)); 
        $pow = min($pow, count($units) - 1); 
        $bytes /= (1 << (10 * $pow)); 

        return round($bytes, $precision) . ' ' . $units[$pow]; 
} 

// Hooked
function ua_admin_custom_filesize_on_edit_media_screen() {
        global $post; // $post = get_post();
        $filesize = @filesize(get_attached_file($post->ID));

        if ( ! empty( $filesize ) && is_numeric( $filesize ) && $filesize > 0 ) : ?>
                <div class="misc-pub-section">
                        <?php _e( 'File size:' ); ?> <strong><?php echo ua_formatBytes( $filesize ); ?></strong>
                </div>
        <?php
        endif;
}
add_action( 'attachment_submitbox_misc_actions', 'ua_admin_custom_filesize_on_edit_media_screen', 99 );
```